# MongoDB replica set error reading from secondary (using primaryPreferred) after primary shut down

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I created a MongoDB replica set and I am testing the failover scenarios.

I am using pymongo as my driver and I am connecting using an `mongodb+srv://` connection string and I set my `readPreference` to `primaryPreferred`.

However when I shut down my primary server I get the following error from pymongo (prior to the secondary assuming the role of the primary, once the secondary is primary it works as expected), my question is that since I am using a `readPreference` of `primaryPreferred` shouldn't the read be directed to the secondary and not error out?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\main.py", line 18, in main
    commands[command](*args)
  File ".\main.py", line 26, in print_specs
    for db in client.list_databases():
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1890, in list_databases
    res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 748, in _retryable_read_command
    return self.__client._retryable_read(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1453, in _retryable_read
    server = self._select_server(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1253, in _select_server
    server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 233, in select_server
    return random.choice(self.select_servers(selector,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 192, in select_servers
    server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 208, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members match selector "Primary()"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have either:

- Not specified the read preference at all, or specified it incorrectly, or
- Have issued an operation that doesn't respect read preference, or
- Are attempting a write, to which read preference doesn't apply.

Going by the stack trace, you are listing databases which is a read operation so it's one of the first two reasons.